# Read OTP SMS from IOS device and send in API in background

Tags: ios, flutter, background-service

```
[ otptextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode ]
```

I tried this code which is in swift language but that is not what I want.
I want a background service for my iPhone to read my own SMS to another device, or a google chart sheet.
And also, is it possible to do it in any other languages like flutter or python?
Only just I want to read SMS from an ios device by any programming language without jailbreak.

Comment: Due to security issues, Apps on iOS can't read sms text messages.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't read the whole content of SMS messages since this will violate the user's privacy.

Comment: But I want to share SMS between my own devices. I tried so hard in this project please somehow help me.

Answer (score 1):

Due to security issues, Apps on iOS can't read sms text messages. I wasted a lot of my time trying to figure that out. IOS keyboard will always recognise OTP and keep the OTP in their clipboard so its easy to paste it in otp field, that's all you can do for now.

Comment: thanks but, I want to do it in the background as we are doing it like android programming. I don't want to touch the clipboard.

Comment: It is not possible in IOS currently, sorry I couldn't be of much help. Even I looked for this solution a long time and had to give up.

Answer (score 1):

##### Foreword:

I've not actually implemented any of the following.  This is purely a research-based answer done for an app I wrote.  That said, some of the other answers here are incorrect (even at their time of writing), or at least incomplete, so hopefully this will provide more detail.

##### Research:

###### Regarding reading OTPs:

As others have mentioned, it *is* possible to read one-time passwords on iOS.  There is a Flutter package specifically for this, [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill), which has been available for a few years now.

###### Regarding reading SMS, in general:

As others have mentioned, reading SMS messages from an iOS app is *not* currently permitted.  ***However***, depending on the nature of your needs, it *is* possible via iOS's "SMS and Call Spam Reporting" feature, which integrates your functionality into iOS's built-in apps, for the purpose of spam reporting.  In this context, yes, you can read the contents of one or more of the user's SMS messages via the [ILMessageCommunication class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/ilmessagecommunication#2991630), which clearly indicates that it provides "The content of the SMS message."

As of writing this, I could find no Flutter package available that supported this feature.

###### Regarding sending messages in the background:

There are at least two Flutter packages that do this, [flutter_sms](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms) and [sms_advanced](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_advanced).  For an updated list, look on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=platform%3Aios+sms+send).